# Proving Natural Predecessor existence using Well Order

Tags: induction, natural-numbers, peano-axioms, well-orders

I know that the Principle of Induction is equivalent to Well Order at least in Natural Numbers, but I have seen that the demonstration of Induction using Well Order uses the existence of Predecessor:

1. [Assume Induction]: Suppose $P(0)$ is true, and $P(n+1)$ is true whenever $P(n)$ is true.
2. [$S$ definition]: Let $S$ be the non-empty set of $k$ for which $P(k)$ is not true.
3. [Well-Order]: By well-ordering $S$ has a least element, which cannot be $k = 0$.
4. [Predecessor & Contradiction]: But then $P(k-1)$ is true, and so $P(k)$ is true.

When using $P(k-1)$ at [4.] it is assumed that $k-1$ exists as a Predecessor of $k$, but how would one demonstrate Predecesor existence using Peano Axioms without Induction Principle? That is to say, all Peano Axioms but replacing the Principle of Induction with the Principle of Well Order.

Comment: Since $k\ne 0$, it is a successor of some element.

Comment: Are you refering to a Peano Axiom?

Comment: You can prove (using WO) that $n=0 \lor n > 0$ ? If so, you can prove $n=0 \lor \exists b (n=s(b))$ (where $s(x)$ is the *successor* function. Thus, define $n \ne 0 \to (p(n)=m \leftrightarrow n=s(m))$.

Comment: Interesting. Peano Axioms does not have a definition for $<$ Thus $n>0=>∃p:n=s(p)$ is not a proposition. It is an edge if the answer to my question is "Undecidable"

Comment: $<$ is defined in PA with $n < m \leftrightarrow \exists k (m=n+s(k))$.

Comment: Good to know I am probably going to consider that yet with PA I am referring to the 5 https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PeanosAxioms.html.